# How do I fix my media query to change text size?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a media query to reduce the size of a text. Sounds simple enough, right? I can't seem to see what I'm missing.

HTML:

```
<div class="fp-featured">
<div class="fp-title">TITLE</div>
<p class="text1 inline-edit-editable">Text 1 here<br />
<span class="text2" style="font-size: 56pt;">Text 2 here!</span></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.fp-featured > span {
font-size: 12pt;
}
}
```

Also tried just shooting for the span class

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.text2 {
font-size: 12pt;
}
}
```

As I shrink the window, nothing changes. I don't know if I'm declaring the classes wrong or the order of it but i just can't get the text to reduce in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have inline css applied to your text2 element which has higher priority than your regular css in the stylesheet.
To increase priority of your stylesheet css use !important rule.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.text2 {
font-size: 12pt!important;
}
}
```

Or alternatively you can set your initial text side in your stylesheet and remove the inline style declaration from your html.

Comment: thank you! I forgot all about which takes priority. And I unfortunately can't edit that specific class, thus the inline style. But this worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Add in your CSS, and remove the inline CSS. [Example](https://www.lifewire.com/avoid-inline-styles-for-css-3466846)

```
.text2 {
   font-size: 56pt;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of things wrong here.

1. As you have written `inline css` to `span` it can only be overwritten with a `css` with `!importans` property. Example: `font-size: 12pt!important;`
2. `.fp-featured > span` will only select `span`'s of `.fp-featured` if you want to select all `descendants` of `.fp-featured` use `.fp-featured span`.

Overall I would suggest to `remove` the inline `css` and write the following css

```
.fp-featured span {
    font-size: 56pt;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .fp-featured span {
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
}
```